# ng-repeat orderBy with double digit number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have names such as:

```
Name - Page 9
Name - Page 2
Name - Page 6
Name - Page 15
Name - Page 1
Name - Page 12
Name - Page 14
Name - Page 13
Name - Page 10
Name - Page 11
```

Currently I am doing:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in results | orderBy:'-name'">
{{ data.name }}
</div>
```

But it doesn't order it with the numbers taken into consideration.

Does anyone know how I can make sure it is ordered according to the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="app">
        <div data-ng-controller="testC">
        <div ng-repeat="data in results | orderBy:['name']">-{{data.name}}</div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('testC', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.results = [{'name':'Page 21'},
        {'name':'Page 12'},
        {'name':'Page 10'},
        {'name':'Page 01'},
        {'name':'Page 30'},
        {'name':'Page 15'},
        {'name':'Page 05'}];
        }]);
</script>
```

it is working for me ,please try once .
https://jsfiddle.net/shivtumca12/nqbLLr4x/
and also

https://jsfiddle.net/shivtumca12/LxLu8v70/

Comment: That's because you put a `0` in front of single digit numbers-  ie. `01` and not `1`

Comment: @bryan but second one  is working fine ,once check both ,please let me know ,where i am wrong .

Comment: Your second jsfiddle code does not provide solution to the question as you have ignored text and only have numbers there. The question asks for a way to sort items in order where there is a text with a number in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as expected. Check this plunker that I created. 
[Plunker Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/IjJ11KgjuqFqST1M7W7R?p=preview)

Edit: To handle double digits you can write a custom sort function like this:

```
 $scope.myValueFunction = function(value) {
  var numpart = value.name.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
  return -(numpart-1000);
}
```

What this does is extract the number part and make it a sortable number. You can remove the preceding -ve sign to get ascending order.

Then in your html, you can call this function like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:myValueFunction">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: sorry fixed my question, what about with double digits?